# Replacing google font url with generated font squirrel font kit

Tags: css, fonts

I have written a web application which uses the yaml css framework. One of the lines in the yaml css file is....

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400italic,700|Droid+Sans:700);

The internet is very slow at my company and I want to replace that download with a local copy of the font.

To try to achieve this I went to http://www.google.com/fonts, downloaded the DroidSans and DroidSerif fonts. The files I get are...

- fonts.DroidSerif-Italic.ttf
- fonts/DroidSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
- fonts/DroidSerif-Bold.ttf
- fonts/DroidSerif.ttf
- fonts.DroidSans.ttf
- fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf

I then went to http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and created 1 font kit for all my DroidSerif fonts and 1 font kit for all my DroidSans fonts.

I am a bit stuck now though because having a look at the demos in the generated font kits they have given a different font-face declaration per ttf file. In other words I have a number of font-face declarations...

```
@font-face {font-family: 'droid_serifbold'; ...
@font-face {font-family: 'droid_serifitalic'; ...
@font-face {font-family: 'droid_serifbold_italic'; ...
@font-face {font-family: 'droid_serifregular'; ...
...and same for droid sans...
```

But the yaml CSS framework doesn't use the fonts that way. Instead they have one definition of the font and then specify different font-weights...

```
  body {
    font-family: "Droid Serif", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    ...
  }

  h6 {
    font-family: "Droid Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;

  q {
    font-family: "Droid Serif", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-style: italic;

  b {
     font-weight: bold;
```

I would rather not change the yaml css as I might muck it up. My question is how can I change the font-face declarations provided to me from the font squirrel font kit to match the font-weight style my css is using?

thanks

Comment: You would have to combine all the font faces into a single font file and generate the webfonts from that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the site you had in the first place: [Google Fonts](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400italic,700|Droid+Sans:700), and take a look at the generated code,

you can realize you need to:

Download these 4 files:

- [Droid Sans Bold](http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v4/EFpQQyG9GqCrobXxL-KRMQFhaRv2pGgT5Kf0An0s4MM.woff)
- [Droid Serif](http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidserif/v4/0AKsP294HTD-nvJgucYTaIbN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff)
- [Droid Serif Bold](http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidserif/v4/QQt14e8dY39u-eYBZmppwTqR_3kx9_hJXbbyU8S6IN0.woff)
- [Droid Serif Italic](http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidserif/v4/cj2hUnSRBhwmSPr9kS5899kZXW4sYc4BjuAIFc1SXII.woff)

Rename all appropriately and place in the `fonts` folder:

- fonts/**DroidSans-Bold**.woff
- fonts/**DroidSerif**.woff
- fonts/**DroidSerif-Bold**.woff
- fonts/**DroidSerif-Italic**.woff

And then use this code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Droid Sans Bold'), local('DroidSans-Bold'), url('fonts/DroidSans-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Droid Serif'), local('DroidSerif'), url('fonts/DroidSerif.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Droid Serif Bold'), local('DroidSerif-Bold'), url('fonts/DroidSerif-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Droid Serif Italic'), local('DroidSerif-Italic'), url('fonts/DroidSerif-Italic.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Comment: Oh god. I'm embarrassed. I didn't think to just put the url in the browser and see what came up. But it all makes sense now because that url was a css import hence it should be importing a snippet of css. I did everything you suggested and it has worked like a charm. Thank you. At lease in the process of investigating how to do this I discovered how to use font squirrel. It may come in handy int he future.